# Cucumber, selenium, ruby: best practices to check 301 redirect

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, cucumber

I need to check 301 redirect. 
So I have old URLs that should redirect to new ones.
What are the best practices to verify it?
 Now I'm thinking about simple way: navigate to an old URL and check that the new URL is correct and corresponding page displays. Can I check that it was 301 redirect?
I found the following article: http://www.natontesting.com/2010/09/06/announcing-responsalizr-test-http-response-codes-in-ruby/

but after redirection I see the current status code =200
any suggestion how can I catch 301 status code?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I do not think there is a lot of value in verifying the status code. From a user's perspective, all they care about is that if they go to an old url, they get re-directed to the new url. How the redirection is implemented, should not matter.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do it in a feature spec. In a feature spec (cucumber), you test the site how the user sees it, and the user doesn't care what the status code was. If you really care about the response, do it in a controller or better request spec. With rspec, it could look like this:

```
describe 'redirects' do
  context 'on GET /old_users' do
    before do
      get '/old_users'
    end

    it 'redirects /old_users to /users' do
      expect(response).to redirect_to('/users')
    end

    it 'responds with a 301 - Permanently moved' do
      expect(response.status).to eq(301)
    end
  end
end
```

https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/request-specs/request-spec